# Linq query with a Join, not returning the correct results

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

i've got the following code, which compiles but doesn't retrieve the correct results.

I'm trying to retrieve all the Banned log entries for people who have been recorded at cheating on a gaming server.

The database (in this case, two IList tables) has two simple *tables*.

- GameFiles : the game which has a log file .. which we parse.
- LogEntries : an individual entry in a log file. Each game file has mother-bucket load of log entries.

So this is a simple 1 to many relationship.

Currently it's retrieving all the results for GameType.BattleField2, but not for GameType.CallOfDuty4. I have confirmed that the IList gameFiles does contain some data for GameType.BattleField2 and for GameType.CallOfDuty4. I have also confirmed that each of those files has log entries.

So, can someone have a look at this linq and tell me what i've done wrong?

```
public IList<LogEntry> BannedEntries(GameType? gameType)
{
    var query = from l in _logEntryRepository.GetLogEntries()
                join g in _gamefileRepository.GetGameFiles()
                on l.GameFileId equals g.GameFileId into JoinedResult
                from x in JoinedResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new 
                { 
                    LogEntry = l,
                    GameFile = x
                };

    if (gameType.HasValue)
    {
        query = from q in query
                where q.GameFile.GameType == gameType
                select q;
    }

    // Now retrieve only LogEntries.
    return (from q in query
            where q.LogEntry.EventType == EventType.BannableViolation
            select q.LogEntry)
            .ToListIfNotNullOrEmpty();
}
```

Comment: did u mean to use select new { LogEntry = l, gameFile = g } ?

Comment: @Mahesh - nope. if u try to do that, you will get a compiler error. I know .. cause that was what i tried, first :)

Comment: I generally use from instead of join, like "from l in logentries from g in gamesRepo something = somethingelse", worth a try?

Comment: You're reusing your query variable - logically there's no reason why it won't work but at the very least its confusing and at worse I can see wierd things happening - especially as the query itself doens't actually happen 'til you attempt enumerate stuff. I can sort of see what you're trying for but being more explicit is liable to make it easier to test intermediate results.

Comment: agreed Murph. Actually, the query works great. My assuption/test that the data was correct in the IList<..> was wrong -> the data was missing. BUT, i've been trying to clean up this query .. like pcambell's suggestion .. with little luck. :(

Comment: @Pure; updated answer. If not working, are you able to post your DDL statements for the tables? This would help me track down the right statements for my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want the logs, try this simplified-for-demo-only code:

```
string optionalGameType = "COD4";
//retrieve log entries for BANNED, with optional specified game type
List<LogFile> banned = logs.Where(x => x.EventType == "banned")
                 .WhereIf(optionalGameType.Length > 0, (x => x.GameFileID == games.Where(g => g.GameType == optionalGameType).SingleOrDefault().GameFileID))
                 .ToList();           

int cod4BannedCount = banned.Count;

return banned;
```

I used a string instead of your custom type, and a string instead of your EventType.BannableViolation. It'd be easy for you to use your custom types instead.

The [full source/proof is at this pastebin page](http://pastebin.ca/1720168).

Check out the [WhereIf extension method](http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=242). It's helped me a few times to avoid those conditionals as separate statements.

Given that example, your code might be refactored to look something like this:

```
List<LogEntry> banned = _logEntryRepository.GetLogEntries()
                .Where(x => x.EventType == EventType.BannableViolation)
                .WhereIf(gameType.HasValue,
                    (x => x.GameFile.GameType == _gamefileRepository.GetGameFiles()
                                         .Where(g => g.GameType == gameType) 
                                         .SingleOrDefault()
                                         .GameType
                     ))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: hmm. interesting :) I like this WhereIf extension method. Problem with this code is, with this part `.WhereIf(gameType.HasValue, (x => x.GameType == <snip>)) won't/doesn't work .. because `x` is representing a LogEntry .. which doesn't have a property called `GameType` ... that exists on a `GameFile` type.

Comment: @ PCambell - thanks for the code update. Still doesn't compile. I'm sure it's because the *x => x.<whatever>* represents a logEntry variable .. which doesn't have a reference up to a GameFile..... ?? Maybe a JOIN is required?

Comment: even though this still didn't work for me, i'll give it a tick cause it was pretty close / good / inspiring :)